# XP POSReady and TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, vbscript, windows-xp, tls1.2, posready

I'm trying to use TLS 1.2 on Windows XP POSReady after having installed the Microsoft released KB4019276 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows) and enabled it in registry.

My very simple code to test it is :

```
Option Explicit

Const   WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols = 9
Const   SecureProtocol_SSL2 = 8, SecureProtocol_SSL3 = 32, _
        SecureProtocol_TLS1 = 128, SecureProtocol_TLS1_1 = 512, _
        SecureProtocol_TLS1_2 = 2048

Dim objHTTP
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
objHTTP.open "GET", "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check", False
objHTTP.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols) = SecureProtocol_TLS1_2
objHTTP.Send
If objHTTP.WaitForResponse(30) Then 'wait up to 30 seconds
    WScript.Echo "Status : " & objHTTP.Status & "<br />"
    WScript.Echo "Response Length : " & LenB(objHTTP.ResponseBody)
    WScript.Echo "Response Text : " & objHTTP.ResponseText
Else
    WScript.Write "Request timed out"
End If
Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

but anything over TLS 1.0 is giving me the error :

```
Invalid argument for Option
```

while, disabling SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 I'me getting an error about not being able to negotiate a security protocol.

any advice ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IF actually have the same problem on my expermiental Winxp sp3 (all further updates included). 
I found out that WINHTTP.DLL does still not contain the API Call function
SECUREPROTOCOL_TLS1_1  as well as SECUREPROTOCOL_TLS1_2. 
Causing the "invalid option" error.

So, this syntax isn't supported on standard XP systems !
(winhttp.dll not getting updated). ONly embeddedXP might have optained an updated winhttp.dll file accepting this option.

I now make efforts to somehow obtain the updated ominous winhttp.dll.

Results will be reported here.

Comment: A similar problem existed for the Server 2008 and old windows 7 previously.  Just look here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/97e37a88-f7f8-424a-b8bd-e089f1bbea84/upgrade-winhttpdll-version-to-support-tls-11-and-tls-12-windows-2008-r2-and-windows-7?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification.  So this problem seems to apply now in analogy for windows XP (maybe as mentioned embeddedXP 2009 and POSReady have gotten an upgraded winhttp.dll to support this function but regular XP obviously have not)

Comment: There is no such upgraded DLL for XP however. Instead there is an additional Setting in the Registry to facilitate properly. See under KB3140245.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3140245 I also have found that in the updated SCHANNEL.DLL in XP are references to a new line of registry entries to be made in the \Cryptography branches since it references to these (very analog to those in windows 7).

Comment: I already tried both without success. It seem that the support in XP PosReady is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [ssllabs client test](https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) looks like after applying KB4019276

```
Protocols

TLS 1.3                                     No
TLS 1.2                                     Yes*
TLS 1.1                                     Yes*
TLS 1.0                                     Yes*
SSL 3                                       Yes*
SSL 2                                       No          


Cipher Suites (in order of preference)

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)      WEAK      256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)      WEAK      128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)         WEAK      256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)         WEAK      128
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)              INSECURE  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)              INSECURE  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)         WEAK      112
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6a)  WEAK      256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x40)  WEAK      128
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x13)    WEAK      112


Protocol Details        

Server Name Indication (SNI)                No          
Secure Renegotiation                        Yes                 
TLS compression                             No      
Session tickets                             No      
OCSP stapling                               No                  
Signature algorithms                        SHA256/RSA, SHA384/RSA, SHA1/RSA, SHA1/DSA, SHA512/RSA                                  
Named Groups                                -                        
Next Protocol Negotiation                   No          
Application Layer Protocol Negotiation      No      
SSL 2 handshake compatibility               No
```

There are no ECDHE negotiating cipher suites so everything is deemed WEAK or outright INSECURE.

Answer (score -2):

Folks. The relevant Update for enabling TLS 1.2 in XP has been re-released
as of 18 Feb 2018.  (KB4019276). Downloaded from the MS UpdateCatalog.
This is a correction for the (obviously buggy) initial release in October 2017.
Which now WORKS correctly !

Features in IE8 :   TLS 1.2  enabled

included also :  TLS Session Ticket support

NEW available Suites (howsmyssl.com, ssllabs):

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b) FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9) FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   FS    256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   FS 128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   FS 256

Supported Named groups for EC : secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1

Kind Regards!

BerndP